# Reading POST data from Google App Engine pipeline callback

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pipeline, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to download data from an external API. There's going to be a lot of downloads, so I want to use pipelines for easier parallelization. The way the API is set up, I can make a request to start a download job, and pass a postback url in that request. When the download job finishes, their API sends a POST to the given url. I want to do the following:

```
class DownloadPipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):
    async = True
    public_callbacks = True

    def run(self, filename):
        postback = self.get_callback_url()
        # make API request with postback as a param

    def callback(self):
        # Read data from the POST
```

However, all the docs I've read online only have examples of GET requests on the callback url, where data is passed through a query string on the URL. Is there a way to read POST data instead?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both the [POST](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines/blob/master/python/src/pipeline/pipeline.py#L2778) and [GET](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines/blob/master/python/src/pipeline/pipeline.py#L2781) both call over to [run_callback()](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines/blob/master/python/src/pipeline/pipeline.py#L2802) ... so you should be able to do either